# Is Stack Overflow the correct place to ask for improvements to my user interface?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope

I have came up with some user interface problems. Is it OK to ask opinions about it on Stack Overflow or should I find some other channel for this type of question?

An example question: I have a submit button below my form and I decided to use purple font on it to show that the button really is the form's submit button. Do you think this purple colour is OK?

Comment: By the way, I don't know if that example is *actually* your question, but please don't mess with the standard font colours unless you have an extremely good reason to.  Rainbow fonts are eyesores, not to mention telltale signs of an amateur designer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend the [User Interface Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) site instead.

A question like that would *probably* get closed on Stack Overflow; even if it doesn't, you'll probably get a better answer on UI.SE.

Comment: +1 I was about to recommend the same thing.